# Infinite $digest Loop with sortby

Tags: angularjs

I have very simple form:

```
<form>
    <label><input type="radio" name="sortby" value="created" checked ng-model="sortby"> By creation date</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="sortby" value="text" ng-model="sortby"> By text</label>
</form>

<div ng-repeat="todo in TodoList.getTodos() | orderBy: sortby">
    <h1>{{ todo.text }}</h1>
</div>
```

But this produces `Error: $rootScope:infdig. Infinite $digest Loop` when switch sorting. How to make this switch working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems like your TodoList.getTodos() function generates a new array every time it is called, this common mistake is explained at https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig. The solution is to keep your todoList in a variable, which should be updated only when the list is changed, and TodoList.getTodos() function just returns this variable:

```
// should be updated only when the list is changed 
var todoList= [ YOUR TODO LIST ];

TodoList.getTodos = function() {
  return todoList;
};
```